# Set NSMutableArray to the new NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

```
@implementation RightViewController{
    NSMutableArray * tableArray;
}

@synthesize tableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}


- (void)refreshTable: (NSMutableArray*)resultsArray{
    [tableArray setArray:resultsArray];    
    NSLog(@"resultsArray : %d : %d", [tableArray count] , [resultsArray count]);

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

It shows me :  resultsArray : 0 : 78

Why can't I set information to this array? 
I do call refreshTable from another controller like this:

```
[[[RightViewController alloc] init] refreshTable:resultsArray];
```

**Updated:**

```
tableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:resultsArray];
```

worked for me.

After that i do

```
- (IBAction)reloadTableButton:(id)sender {
    [self refreshTable:tableArray];
}
```

and it's shows me : resultsArray : 0 : 0

Why  is tableArray array empty?

Comment: r u tring like tablearray=resultsArray

Comment: Are you sure your resultsArray is not nil or have no items?

Comment: It doesn't work because your ivar is always an empty array, and I guess that your `tableView` data source is baked by said array.

Comment: how about a strong array property ??

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your `tableArray` variable like so :

```
tableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:resultsArray];
```

You might not be retaining your mutable array I would suggest making a `@property` for your tableArray. Place this before your `@synthesize`

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tableArray;
```

Comment: Worked for me. Can you see that is wrong with updated info in a question?

Comment: That should work better. But the reason is not that setArray was wrong in any way. The reason might be that viewDidLoad may not have been called before refreshTable is executed. And Victor did not initialize his array in init but in view did load. Therefore setArray may have been sent to a nil object and count may have been sent to a nil object. It should therefore return 0 nor nil.  Your suggestion is fine and moving `tableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` to the init method should work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //don't do anything with the array here! 
    //refreshTable may well be called before the view is loaded
}


- (void)refreshTable: (NSMutableArray*)resultsArray{

    if (!self.tableArray) // if it does not exist, then create it on the fly. 
        self.tableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [tableArray setArray:resultsArray];    
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Option 2:

```
- (MyClass*) init {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
     self.tableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //don't do anything with the array here! 
}


- (void)refreshTable: (NSMutableArray*)resultsArray{
    [tableArray setArray:resultsArray]; // you can be sure that init was invoked earlier.    
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Option 3:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //don't do anything with the array here! 
}


- (void)refreshTable: (NSMutableArray*)resultsArray{
    self.tableArray = [NSMutalbeArray arrayWithArray:resultsArray];   //This creates a new array as a copy of resultsArray and assigns it to tableArray. No need to initialize anything. 
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe it should work

```
RightViewController *controller = [[RightViewController alloc] init];
[controller refreshTable:resultsArray];
```

Comment: Your answer would be considerably better if you could explain _why_.

Comment: I would not sign in blood that viewDidLoad has been called before refreshTable is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

```
@implementation RightViewController{
    NSMutableArray * tableArray;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tableArray; //use the keyword "retain" instead of "strong" in below iOS 5

@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize tableArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}


- (void)refreshTable: (NSMutableArray*)resultsArray{

     self.tableArray = resultsArray;

    NSLog(@"resultsArray : %d : %d", [tableArray count] , [resultsArray count]);

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```